# Can we blacklist the "christianity" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Based on experience on other sites, tags that cover most of all of the subject matter or the site are particularly insidious and often get used when people don't want to put any more effort into picking a real tag.

I would like to suggest that we get [christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) and [christian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian) blacklisted right off the bat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These two tags have been added to the blacklist.

Answer (score 12):

I agree, both of those are meta tags that

A. cannot stand alone on a question

B. can be equally added to every question on the site.

They should be blacklisted.